# In Objective-C, what difference does it make when initWith returns (Fraction *) and init returns (id)?

Tags: objective-c

In Stephen Kochan's Objective-C book (I have the 3rd Edition), one init function returns `Fraction *` and one returns `id`:

```
-(Fraction *) initWith: (int) n: (int) d {
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
        [self setTo: n over: d];

    return self;
}

-(id) init {
    return [self initWith: 0 over: 0];
}
```

(it is on page 198 to 199 of the book).  Why is that, and does it matter if both return `Fraction *` or both return `id` (or have `init` return `Fraction *` and `initWith` return `id`)?  What are the side effects of doing so, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Init` methods typically return the `id` type because they don't necessarily return an object of the class they belong to.

For instance, `-[NSMutableArray init]` actually returns a `NSCFMutableArray` object.

Answer (score 1):

Favor to return `id` from initializers.

You can use the other syntax, but it's very noisy in practice (unless you never ever subclass and the selector is guaranteed to be unique).

Convenience constructors are fine, but it's safest to add the type name to the constructor:

```
+ (Fraction *)newFractionWithNumerator:(int)pNumerator denominator:(int)pDenominator;
```

Without those measures, your program will be exposed to several compiler warnings and errors.

Comment: Justin is right, but to expand on why: Using a statically typed return value can be problematic, because if another class has an initializer with the same name (even a subclass!), the compiler will throw type errors. Using `id` prevents this, and in practice you don't lose any type safety because you almost never do something with the result of `init` but assign it to a statically typed variable.

Comment: FYI, you generally don't want your convenience constructors to begin with "new" — that implies that the method returns an owning reference (ARC even enforces this).

Comment: @Chuck there's nothing wrong with returning +1. I typically do it this way.

Comment: Oh, I know it isn't wrong, but that isn't generally called a "convenience constructor". That term is used in the Cocoa docs to refer to methods like `arrayWithObjects:`, which return a net-0 instance. A `new` method is just an old-style constructor, no convenience added. I didn't want people getting confused, because the difference is important.

Comment: By the way, pointers to a class will bind to any pointer of a parent class without a warning. For instance, you could assign a `Fraction*` to a `NSObject*` variable without problem (assuming `Fraction` inherits from `NSObject`).

Comment: @zneak right, the compiler understands class hierarchies; upcasting is not the origin of the issues Chuck and I are referring to. it's downcasting (Base->Derived). if the initializer returns an object with qualified objc typename, then the compiler will complain when you attempt to assign the result to a subclass.